# Can you explain this layout weirdness?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, layout, cross-browser

On this page:

http://www.ntelos.com/wireline/main

In both IE7 and FF, but not Chrome or IE6, the layout of this page is very odd.  Everything is fine except that the page width is way off.  It doesn't occur anywhere else in the site.

The page uses XHTML Strict, CSS, and jQuery to get the parts to work.  Any clues?

Thanks very much for any assistance.

Frank

Comment: Can you describe your definition of odd? I am using FF and the page seems normal to me. Also in IE8, content of the page, including its width seemed normal.

Comment: @Frank - In addition to Anthony, I just tried the page in IE7 and everything looked good.

Comment: It looks exactly the same in FF IE8 and Chrome

Comment: Thanks to Kevin Pang for fixing my hasty and embarrassing typos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the "infinite_thumbs" classed div.

Try setting width, or max-width on it.  200px worked for me to fix the problem.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what browser are you on?

Comment: width: 150px seems to be the best. I'm on Firefox 3.6.

Comment: FF3.2.7 on Vista, FF3.0.17 Mac.  The content of the page looks fine in the viewport, but there is a horizontal scrollbar that allows to scroll to the right.